# "docker-compose" does not appear to allow or build from local images

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I've been trying for the last 2 days to get a small edit to a Dockerfile tested on a multi-container set that uses `docker-compose`.

I can build, and tag the container locally, but as soon as I run 'docker-compose' it pulls from the registry copy (contrary to the docker-compose documentation).

If I run `docker build .` on the directory itself, the container is found correctly, but running "docker-compose build" fails.

```
bash-3.2$ docker images
REPOSITORY            TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED                VIRTUAL SIZE
busbyjon/heroku-php   latest              c6c60910a924        58 minutes ago      1.754 GB
mysql                 latest              d7da97aedce5        3 days ago          324.3 MB
heroku/cedar          14                  ef12eade669a        2 weeks ago         1.265 GB
bash-3.2$ docker-compose build
cleardb uses an image, skipping
Building shell...
Step 0 : FROM busbyjon/heroku-php
Pulling repository docker.io/busbyjon/heroku-php
Service 'shell' failed to build: Error: image busbyjon/heroku-php:latest not found
```

Note how `busbyjon/heroku-php` is listed as an image, but is not found.  It does not seem to matter what I tag this image as (it can be "test" and it still doesn't work!).

Please help!

Comment: It would work. What version of `docker` and `docker-compose` are you using?

Comment: Sounds like you've hit this issue - https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/1568

Comment: Yep! That looks about right - guess I'll need to wait for this fix to get released - in the mean time I've pushed my changes to docker hub to work around this issue

Comment: Still seeing this in 1.5.2  :-(

Answer (score 2):

I was able to overcome similar issue by tagging my image like this:

- `myservice` or `local/myservice`

This did not work for me:

- `my-service`

Maybe it is not the cause.. but try to remove dashes from your image tag.
To retag your image run: `docker tag busbyjon/heroku-php herokuphp` and then use image name `herokuphp` in `docker-compose.yml`

Answer (score 1):

This is likely due to this bug: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/1568 (unable to find locally built image)